# Как вставить изображение в QTextEdit?

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, qtextedit, qtextdocument

Есть ли возможность вставки изображений, таблиц в QTextEdit? 
Если да, то какой метод за это отвечает?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

После ответа @gil9red и добавить вроде нечего, только продемонстрировать в фрагменте кода, как это может выглядеть)

Да и перетаскивать изображения в `QTextEdit` тоже можно.

```
import os
import sys

from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *

IMAGE_EXTENSIONS = ['.jpg','.png','.bmp']

def splitext(p):
    return os.path.splitext(p)[1].lower()

class TextEdit(QTextEdit):

    def canInsertFromMimeData(self, source):
        if source.hasImage():
            return True
        else:
            return super(TextEdit, self).canInsertFromMimeData(source)

    def insertFromMimeData(self, source):
        cursor = self.textCursor()
        document = self.document()
        if source.hasUrls():
            for u in source.urls():
                file_ext = splitext(str(u.toLocalFile()))
                if u.isLocalFile() and file_ext in IMAGE_EXTENSIONS:
                    image = QImage(u.toLocalFile())
                    document.addResource(QTextDocument.ImageResource, u, image)
                    cursor.insertImage(u.toLocalFile())
                else:
                    break
            else:
                return

        super(TextEdit, self).insertFromMimeData(source)


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.editor = TextEdit()
        self.editor.setAcceptRichText(False)
        self.editor.setAutoFormatting(QTextEdit.AutoAll)
        font = QFont('Times', 12)
        self.editor.setFont(font)
        self.editor.setFontPointSize(12)
        self.path = None

        layout.addWidget(self.editor)
        container = QWidget()
        container.setLayout(layout)
        self.setCentralWidget(container)

        self.status = QStatusBar()
        self.setStatusBar(self.status)
        file_toolbar = QToolBar("File")
        file_toolbar.setIconSize(QSize(14, 14))
        self.addToolBar(file_toolbar)
        file_menu = self.menuBar().addMenu("&File")

        open_file_action = QAction(QIcon(os.path.join('images', 'blue-folder-open-document.png')), "Open file...", self)
        open_file_action.setStatusTip("Insert file")
        open_file_action.triggered.connect(self.file_open)
        file_menu.addAction(open_file_action)
        file_toolbar.addAction(open_file_action)
        self.show()

    def dialog_critical(self, s):
        dlg = QMessageBox(self)
        dlg.setText(s)
        dlg.setIcon(QMessageBox.Critical)
        dlg.show()

    def file_open(self):
        path, _ = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, "Insert file", "", "HTML documents (*.html);Text documents (*.txt);All files (*.*)")
        try:
            with open(path, 'r') as f:
                text = f.read()
        except Exception as e:
            self.editor.textCursor().insertImage(path)
            self.dialog_critical("Вставляем что-то НЕ текстовое.")
        else:
            self.path = path
            self.editor.textCursor().insertText(text)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setApplicationName("Вставка и перетаскивание изображений в QTextEdit")
    window = MainWindow()
    app.exec_()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 4):

> Есть ли возможность вставки изображений, таблиц в QTextEdit?

Есть

---

> какой метод за это отвечает?

У [QTextEdit](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextedit.html) есть метод возвращающий текстовый курсор [textCursor](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextedit.html#textCursor), а у самого [курсора](http://QTextCursor) есть нужные вам методы:

- [QTextCurdor::insertImage](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextcursor.html#insertImage)
- [QTextCurdor::insertTable](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextcursor.html#insertTable)

Пример использования:

```
text_edit.textCursor().insertImage(...)
```

Comment: С с++ кода у меня еще остался понятный пример работы с теми методами, например для вставки изображения: https://github.com/gil9red/NotesManager/blob/a0f55ecbc58f9e5f4273e7eccf7c8e84961e73db/Note/RichTextNote.cpp#L720

Answer (score 0):

Я немного дописал код @S. Nick, чтобы можно было еще вставлять изображения не сохраненные локально на компьютере (например скриншоты или картинки из интернета)

Оставлю его тут, вдруг кому понадобиться)

```py
class TextEdit(QTextEdit):
    def canInsertFromMimeData(self, source):
        if source.hasImage():
            return True
        else:
            return super(TextEdit, self).canInsertFromMimeData(source)

    def _insert_img(self, u, document, cursor):
        image = QImage(u.toLocalFile())
        document.addResource(QTextDocument.ImageResource, u, image)
        cursor.insertImage(u.toLocalFile())

    @property
    def _image_folder(self):
        path = os.path.join('qt_app', 'images')
        if not os.path.exists(path):
            os.makedirs(path)
        return path

    def insertFromMimeData(self, source):
        cursor = self.textCursor()
        document = self.document()

        if source.hasImage():
            image = source.imageData()
            img_path = os.path.join(self._image_folder, f'{uuid.uuid4()}.jpg')  # TODO ext
            image.save(os.path.join(img_path))
            u = QUrl('file:///' + os.path.join(os.getcwd(), img_path))
            self._insert_img(u, document, cursor)
            return
        elif source.hasUrls():
            for u in source.urls():
                file_ext = splitext(str(u.toLocalFile()))
                if u.isLocalFile() and file_ext in IMAGE_EXTENSIONS:
                    self._insert_img(u, document, cursor)
                else:
                    break
            else:
                return

        super(TextEdit, self).insertFromMimeData(source)
```